# Error while cloning flutter project from Github

Tags: github, build.gradle, flutter, git-clone

I am trying to clone the following Flutter project from Github.

https://github.com/rxlabz/flutter_dropcity

But I am getting the following error in build.gradle using VS Code terminal.

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>
>   > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   >     Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   >     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V

Please help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from the discussion at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10236 that the problem can be fixed with using a newer build version.

For this go to `build.gradle` file in `Android/gradle` folder. Now change android build.gradle version from 2.2.3 (as in the original github repo) to 2.3.3 like so:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help!